# How do I increase my subscriber-base: "On Facebook" App or well FB-integrated Website?

Tags: facebook

Shortly, the question is: is there anything I can do building an "On Facebook" FB-app (iframe) that I cannot do with a "Web" FB-app (website with meta tags)? If yes, is it anyway worth to use "On Facebook" FB-apps?

Long question:
Let's say my only need is to increase the number of subscribers of my website. A possible strategy is to leverage on Facebook and build an App. But Facebook gives me 2 options: "On Facebook" or "Web" Apps. My options then would be:

**Solution 1**

Work on two fronts, "On Facebook" and "Web"
Front 1: Build a very Facebook-like application for Facebook users. All possible plugins, information stream from your friend, post to your wall, FB-recommendations etc etc
Front 2: Build a website which uses Opengraph &C but is not "married" to Facebook. In addition than Facebook, you could sign-up with Google(+), Yahoo etc. No recommendation from Facebook, no information from your FB-friends...

**Solution 2**

1 single front: The website *is* the only Facebook application. This could of course create problems with other social plugins like Google+, but only in the future. I'd then invite new users to log-in through Facebook, ask them to invite their FB-friends, recommend them products through FB=recommendation plugin...

Then: solution 1) I split my "brand" in two (App=90% FB and MySite=90%Mine) 
solution 2) I'd accept part of the FB brand on my site (MySite=30%FB + 70%Mine).

As said, the question is not just about "strategy", it's also about implementation. Technically, it looks to me that all functions are available for both "Web" and "On Facebook" FB-Apps, but I might be wrong. Although the official FB page for "On Facebook" apps (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) says "Beyond these features only available to Apps on Facebook.com....", it looks to me that with "Web" app you can get everything too!

Thanks

PS Most big sites who rely on subscribers (CNN, Amazon, Goodreads etc) do not have an "On Facebook" app....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are additional distribution channels provided to canvas application developers but no additional core functionality. I would need a bit more context to tell you if something is possible on canvas (ie apps.facebook.com) or connect (a website). Let me know if you have any additional questions!

Comment: Thanks Daniel –I think you answered the question. You say there is nothing I can do on canvas which cannot be done on connect...
This also explains why most big retailers/social sites do not have two separate apps.
(About distribution channels: do you mean better FB documentation, built-in audience?)

Comment: Good stuff. I believe the main distribution channel that is available for canvas but not for websites is our [notifications/requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) channel.